# Notification example on Android's site

Tags: android

so I'm quite new to android and I'm working through some of the example code off android's site. The one I'm looking at now is called Notifying the User: http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/index.html.

The example is pretty simple, a user enters in a time in seconds and a message, and a timer is set in the background. Once the time runs out, the user is notified.

So here is a copy of the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seconds_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/ping_text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_seconds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seconds_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/seconds_default"
        android:inputType="numberSigned">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reminder_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_seconds"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/reminder_label" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_reminder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_seconds"
        android:layout_below="@+id/reminder_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/reminder_text"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ping_button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_reminder"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:onClick="onPingClick"
        android:text="@string/ping" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can see that there are two editviews for the user to enter in an the seconds (edit_seconds) and the message (edit_reminder). There is also a button called ping, which when press sends the data to the ServiceIntent.

Below is the code for mainactivity.java:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 * in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License
 * is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express
 * or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */

package com.example.android.pingme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Intent mServiceIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Creates an explicit Intent to start the service that constructs and
        // issues the notification.
        mServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PingService.class);
    }

    /*
     * Gets the values the user entered and adds them to the intent that will be
     * used to launch the IntentService that runs the timer and issues the
     * notification.
     */
    public void onPingClick(View v) {
        int seconds;

        // Gets the reminder text the user entered.
        EditText msgText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_reminder);
        String message = msgText.getText().toString();

        mServiceIntent.putExtra(CommonConstants.EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        mServiceIntent.setAction(CommonConstants.ACTION_PING);
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.timer_start, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // The number of seconds the timer should run.
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_seconds);
        String input = editText.getText().toString();

        if(input == null || input.trim().equals("")){
            // If user didn't enter a value, sets to default.
            seconds = R.string.seconds_default;
        } else {
            seconds = Integer.parseInt(input);
        }
        int milliseconds = (seconds * 1000);
        mServiceIntent.putExtra(CommonConstants.EXTRA_TIMER, milliseconds);
        // Launches IntentService "PingService" to set timer.
        startService(mServiceIntent);
```

You can see from the above in the onPingClick(View v) method that both the editTexts were referenced to variables "msgText" and "editText". The ping button was however never referenced nor was a listener attached to the button so that it starts the services when the button is pressed. However, the app works perfectly on both the emulator and my phone without the button being referenced.

How does android know that clicking the button means the method onPingClick(View v) must be actioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the xml layout for the Button is specified : `android:onClick="onPingClick"`
This sets an onClickListener outside the Java code.

Note that the method mus satisfy the signature:

```
public void someName(View v)
```

It is just another way to set a Click Listener for a View.

Comment: omg. That was so easy. I didn't know that you could set a listener  outside of java code. I was looking everywhere for a listener in the code. I learnt something new today, thanks!

Comment: I always learn something new. Every day. Be happy to learn new things, as they enrich you. ;)